# Connecting client-server Java

Tags: java, compilation, server

How do I connect 2 java classes client-server shown in the link below:

https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/

It says i need to compile using TCPserver, I have tried finding the compiling option in my IDE, which is Netbeans, but I cant seem to locate it anywhere. Could I ask for some tips of how to connect those 2 files so that server file responds to client app ?

Comment: I recommend you first learn to use your tool (IDE) before you try socket programming. There's a huge learning curve between "successfully compile and run an application" and "write a TCP client-server program". Just because you've copied some code, doesn't mean you'll be able to understand and use it.

Comment: Tips?  You have to start an instance of each one (server first) and code the client to connect to the server.

Comment: I'm not planning to write a huge application, I want to play around with this code and hopefully learn something, but for that I need to connect both files, I cant seem to find the answer to that aywhere so I asked here

Comment: Try using the javac and java commands to compile and execute the programs.  Knowing how the java environment works will help you in using an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need start the server (the Serversocket) , which will waiting the client socket to connect.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
try {
      Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();
      System.out.println("read by the server\t" + object);
      ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      objectOutputStream.writeObject("this is message by the server");
   }catch(Excetion e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

The serversocket's accept, and the OIS's readObject() method will blocking the thread, so you must start a new thread.

The client will connect when you create the socket object. After that you can send and receive messages on both sides through streams.

```
// host is the localhost IP
Socket socket = new Socket(host, PORT);
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
objectOutputStream.writeObject("this is the message by the client");
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
try {
    System.out.println("read by the client\t" + objectInputStream.readObject());
    }catch(Excetion e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```